# XMLUnit: removing parent wrapper

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

Is there a way in XMLUnit 2 to make these two documents return as the same (or similar)? I can do some preprocessing to get the child nodes, but I wanted to see if this could be done directly with XMLUnit.

Doc1:

```
<a><b><c>test</c></b></a>
```

Doc2:

```
<c>test</c>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XMLUnit expects to be given the roots of the trees that it is supposed to compare. Once you pick the child node, you can use `Input.fromNode` or a similar approach - but you knew that.

It wouldn't be terribly difficult to extend the input builder or create a `Source` wrapper to enable the selection of the "real root" via XPath or similar means, but there is no built-in solution right now.